# Word 2007: heading 2 number will just not go bold

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, numbering

In my Word 2007 quick styles, I have my headings numbered like

```
1.    Heading 1
1.1   Heading 2
1.1.1 Heading 3
```

They are all in bold, so I expect them to look like:

```
1.    Heading 1
1.1   Heading 2
1.1.1 Heading 3
```

However the numbering on heading 2 just **will not** be bold no matter what I try! It looks like this instead:

```
1.    Heading 1
```

1.1   **Heading 2
1.1.1 Heading 3**

I've even tried completely resetting it but it just doesn't help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. I just opened the numbering dialog and noticed there is a "font settings" button there as well. It was totally weird as nothing was filled in there. The font was blank, the style was blank, and all of the "special effects" checkboxes had a square in them.

Comment: Thanks! Setting the font again did it.